# Upsert array of documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am building MongoDB backed API in Python. I am receiving an array of documents along with few other ids. Here is the structure:

```
{
    a_id: ObjectId("..."),
    b_id: ObjectId("..."),
    all_items: [
        {item_id: ObjectId("..."), other_val: "I am other value"},
        {item_id: ObjectId("..."), other_val: "I am another value"},
        ...
    ]
}
```

All I want to do is: upserting in a collection depending on the `a_id, b_id & item_id` value. So the data will be structured inside collection in a manner given below:

```
{
    a_id: ObjectId("..."),
    b_id: ObjectId("..."),
    item_id: ObjectId("..."),
    other_val: "..."
}
```

So if there exists a document that matches with the `a_id, b_id & item_id`, will be updated, otherwise inserted.

Do I need to loop through the whole `all_items` array for every single upsert? Please advise.

Comment: So if all three does match then `other_val` gets updated for that particular `item_id` or else a new doc with `{
    a_id: ObjectId("..."),
    b_id: ObjectId("..."),
    item_id: ObjectId("..."),
    other_val: "..."
}` gets inserted ?

Comment: @srinivasy yes, correct.

Comment: Is it solved or do you still need any help  ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop through the array; you can use a [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#filter) with a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions), then combine this with your other criteria:

**EDIT: Code example updated**

```
import pymongo
from bson import ObjectId

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

# Data setup
my_dict = {
    'a_id': ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"),
    'b_id': ObjectId("222222222222222222222222"),
    'all_items': [
        {'item_id': ObjectId("333333333333333333333333"), 'other_val': "I am other value"},
        {'item_id': ObjectId("444444444444444444444444"), 'other_val': "I am another value"}
    ]
}

# Filter criteria setup
a_filter = ObjectId("111111111111111111111111")
b_filter = ObjectId("222222222222222222222222")
item_filter = ObjectId("444444444444444444444444")

db.mycollection.delete_many({})

for z in filter(lambda x: x.get('item_id') == item_filter, my_dict['all_items']):
    db.mycollection.replace_one({'a_id': a_filter, 'b_id': b_filter, 'item_id': item_filter},
                                {'a_id': a_filter, 'b_id': b_filter, 'item_id': item_filter,
                                 'other_val': z.get('other_val')},
                                upsert=True)

    break  # Remove this line if you want all matching items not just the first one found
```

gives:

```
> db.mycollection.findOne({}, {'_id': 0})
{
        "a_id" : ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"),
        "b_id" : ObjectId("222222222222222222222222"),
        "item_id" : ObjectId("444444444444444444444444"),
        "other_val" : "I am another value"
}
```

Comment: My concern is not to shape the data, rather upserting them in MongoDB.

Comment: I've updated the exampel code to include the upsert.